# C# MySQL Restore

Tags: c#, mysql

I would like to restore my database in MySQL.

When I try manually using cmd to execute the command, it actually restores into the database but when in C# codes, it does not work.

Please help me see where's the error. Thanks!

```
            using System.IO;
            using System.Diagnostics;

            Process process = new Process();
            process.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.1\bin\mysql.exe";
            process.StartInfo.Arguments = @"--verbose --user=root --password=qwerty123456 test < C:\Users\Aaron\testing.SQL";
            process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
            process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
            process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            process.Start();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't imagine that `< C:\Users\Aaron\testing.SQL` is supported when creating a process, it's syntax specific to the command prompt. Try `cmd /c your_app.exe arguments < file` instead.